# C++ calling superclass with if statment

Tags: c++, if-statement, boost, superclass

I think I am missing something here but can't figure out what..

If I do this, I get compile error "error C2446: ':': no conversion from 'const boost::defer_lock_t' to 'const boost::try_to_lock_t'"

```
public: 
explicit BasicScopedLock( CCondition& condition, bool initiallyLocked = true ) 
    : LockType( condition.mutex, (initiallyLocked == true ? (boost::try_to_lock) : (boost::defer_lock)) ) 
    , m_condition( condition ) 
{ 
}
```

But if I do this, it compiles.

```
public: 
explicit BasicScopedLock( CCondition& condition, bool initiallyLocked = true ) 
    : LockType( condition.mutex, boost::try_to_lock ) 
    , m_condition( condition ) 
{ 
}
```

This works too...

```
public: 
explicit BasicScopedLock( CCondition& condition, bool initiallyLocked = true ) 
    : LockType( condition.mutex, boost::defer_lock ) 
    , m_condition( condition ) 
{ 
}
```

Does anyone have a clue on why compiler doesn't like the if statement here?

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the `if` statement? Did you mean `ternary expression`?

Comment: Where is the `if` statement? Did you mean _conditional expression_?

Comment: What do you mean by "calling a class"?  Methods can be called, not classes (unless you are talking about `operator()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `boost::try_to_lock` and `boost::defer_lock` are of completely unrelated types, and `LockType( condition.mutex, boost::try_to_lock)` and `LockType(condition.mutex, boost::defer_lock)` are invoking separate overloads.  As such, you can't use the ternary operator to pick between them.

Your options are:

A. to find another overload of the `LockType` constructor that will allow you to switch at runtime (this is obviously best)

B. if `LockType` is a moveable type, then you can write a function:

```
CLockType create_lock_type( CMutex& mutex, bool initiallyLocked)
{
    if (initiallyLocked)
        return CLockType(mutex,boost::try_to_lock);
    else
        return CLockType(mutex,boost::defer_lock);
}
```

C.  to use the universal solution to problems in computer science:  add another level of indirection.  Change the declaration of `LockType` to:

```
    std::unique_ptr<CLockType> pLockType;
```

and the initialization to:

```
  : pLockType(initiallyLocked? 
         std::make_unique<CLockType>(condition.mutex, boost::try_to_lock):
         std::make_unqiue<CLockType>(condition.mutex, boost::defer_lock))
```

Comment: You changed `LockType` to `CLockType`?

Comment: Well, I can't agree with your code formatting style, or naming for that operator, but this is definitely a good answer otherwise ;)

Comment: Thank you. I did fix the issue by option B.  Sorry for closing the issue as duplicate. (I am new to Stackoverflow and still learning how to use this website :) ). Happy new year!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  LockType is a variable.  CLockType is the class it is an object of.   If LockType is a base class, then option C will be much harder, and option B will only work if it isn't an abstract class.  What were you saying about guessing?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an `if` statement, but an expression using the *conditional operator*<sup>†</sup>. The "true" and "false" operands to this operator must have the same type (roughly speaking), but (as your compiler says) there is no conversion possible between these `boost::try_to_lock` and `boost::defer_lock`.

Without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a description of what you're trying to do, I cannot give a proper suggestion as to how to achieve your goal, but I can tell you that this is not going to cut it.

<sub><sup>†</sup> Sometimes mistakenly called the "ternary operator", because it is *a* ternary operator and the only one currently defined.</sub>

Comment: It's not "mistakenly called" that. It's simply another common name for it (I'd wager it's the more common one).

Comment: @Barmar: It is mistaken. Erroneous. Wrong. Commonly used? Yes; doesn't make it any less of those three things. Stand up for what is right and just and true, instead of just being another sheep, spreading more misinformation :)

Comment: In language, what's commonly used is what's correct. If everyone says it and understands it, that's what it means.

Comment: @Barmar: Not so. Terminology in this context is defined by the relevant international standard document. You're free to write your own answer using the incorrect terminology if you wish. But it would be better if people tried not to do that, so that there wouldn't then be such a schism between what people think they mean and what they actually mean.

Comment: I'm a firm believer in descriptivism, not prescriptivist.

Comment: @Barmar: That's absolutely your prerogative. Happy New Year!

Comment: You guys are ingenious! Sorry for my bad English.  I didn't know boost::try_to_lock and boost:defer_lock had different type.  Thank you very much and happy new year!

Comment: I am annoyed the question has been closed.  Your problem is as described in the duplicate question, but the solution is not.  If `LockType` is moveable (it probably is), write a function to return a suitably constructed object (and use `if` rather than the ternary operator); if not, add another level of indirection and hold it as a unique_ptr, which is constructed with the appropriate call to `make_unique`  (this time you can use the ternary operator).

Comment: Downvoting because I believe it is perfectly possible to construct helpful suggestions without further information.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Only by guessing, which is harmful when you guess wrong. OP asked what the problem is, and I told them. They seem happy enough. So, not a good reason to downvote IMO.

Comment: @MartinBonner: I agree that the dupeclosure is nonsense, and have reopened accordingly. Look forward to reading your answer!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thanks for removing the closure.  I was going to undo the downvote - but I've left it too long.  Sorry.